# Creating a javascript function to switch classes between list elements depending on which one has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, addclass, toggleclass

I am trying to create a function to change the class on a series of 5 list elements depending on which has been clicked. The goal is to change the style of the element depending on which one is the current element.

I had tried something like this:

```
function addClass(obj)
{
 obj.className="highlight";
}
```

and then added this to my elements:

```
 onclick="addClass(this);
```

but this only added the class to the first element in the list and then did not remove the class when a different one was clicked.

My list elements look like this:

```
     <ul id="circularMenu">

        <a href="#strategy" onclick="addClass(this);"><li id="strategy_link"><h3>Strategy</h3></li></a>
        <a href="#branding"><li id="branding_link" onclick="addClass(this);"><h3>Branding</h3></li></a>
        <a href="#marketing"><li id="marketing_link" onclick="addClass(this);"><h3>Marketing</h3></li></a>
        <a href="#media"><li id="media_link" onclick="addClass(this);"><h3>Media</h3></li></a>
        <a href="#management"> <li id="management_link" onclick="addClass(this);"><h3>Management</h3></li></a>

     </ul>
```

When an item is clicked the url changes, maybe this could be the way to set up the function to change classes depending on the url? I am very new with javascript any ideas on how to make this work would be greatly appreciated.

The current way I have it coded is to change each item when hovered, but I would like the change to remain until a different item is clicked. It can be viewed here: http://perksconsulting.com/dev/capabilties.php The items I am referring to are the black dots on the left side of the page.

Comment: Invalid HTML. Should be `ul > li > a`. You can set a `display:block;` css style on the `a` to get it take up the full size of the `li`.
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.perksconsulting.com%2Fdev%2Fcapabilities.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: where you have ever seen code like this? `<a href="#strategy" onclick="addClass(this);"> <li id="strategy_link"> <h3>Strategy</h3> </li> </a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should use the jQuery `addClass()` method.  You don't need to write your own (your addClass() implementation is buggy, by the way).

Try this:

```
function selectInList(obj)
{
    $("#circularMenu").children("a").removeClass("highlight");
    $(obj).addClass("highlight");
}
```

Then:

```
    <ul id="circularMenu">
        <a href="#strategy" onclick="selectInList(this);"><li id="strategy_link"><h3>Strategy</h3></li></a>
        <a href="#branding"><li id="branding_link" onclick="selectInList(this);"><h3>Branding</h3></li></a>
        <a href="#marketing"><li id="marketing_link" onclick="selectInList(this);"><h3>Marketing</h3></li></a>
        <a href="#media"><li id="media_link" onclick="selectInList(this);"><h3>Media</h3></li></a>
        <a href="#management"> <li id="management_link" onclick="selectInList(this);"><h3>Management</h3></li></a>    
     </ul>
```

Or even better, keep your html clean and let jQuery simplify things:

```
    <ul id="circularMenu">
        <a href="#strategy"><li id="strategy_link"><h3>Strategy</h3></li></a>
        <a href="#branding"><li id="branding_link"><h3>Branding</h3></li></a>
        <a href="#marketing"><li id="marketing_link"><h3>Marketing</h3></li></a>
        <a href="#media"><li id="media_link"><h3>Media</h3></li></a>
        <a href="#management"><li id="management_link"><h3>Management</h3></li></a>
    </ul>
```

Then, somewhere in your page:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#circularMenu").children("a").click(function() { selectInList(this) });
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but instead of making it a function, why not just use $('a').click to do it?  Also, @Jason your onclick in the first item is inside your anchor tag but in the rest is on the li tags.  Is this just a typo, or is this intended?  If it is intended you should make them consistent to either all on the anchor or li tags.

Comment: That does what I need! Thanks. Ryan that was a typo, thanks for pointing it out though.

Another quick question though. Any idea why my css might be breaking down in firefox when it works great in safari and chrome?

Thanks again for the help

Comment: i think you should re-copy past your code: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/circular.html

Comment: @aSeptik - lol, yep it looks like that's where Jason got the code from.

Comment: @Jason - there can be a lot of reasons your css is breaking.  It'd probably be best to post a different question on it though.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out.

```
 function addClass(obj)
    {

      $(obj).addClass("Highlight");
    }
```

Comment: This is pointless.  You can just call $(obj).addClass("Highlight") instead.